# error en resultado calculo matematico - programacion en "C"

Tags: c

estoy comenzando en programacion y practicando unos ejercicios en c. realize el siguiente codigo pero me da error al calcular las horas extras. les explico el ejercicio.
hay que desarrollar un programa que indique cuanto se le paga a los empleados . hasta 40 horas se paga el valor normal , las horas extra se paga x 1.5 . ej : 40 horas x 10 la hora = 400 , 41 horas = 415 ( 400 + 15 de la hora extra). pero hay calcular 41 horas me esta dando 425.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main()
    {
float cant_horas, pago, extra, salario;

while (cant_horas != -1)
{
    printf("ingrese cantidad de horas trabajadas: ");
    scanf("%f", &cant_horas);

    if (cant_horas != -1)

    {
        printf("ingrese valor de hora trabajo : $  ");
        scanf("%f", &pago);

        salario = pago * cant_horas;

        if (cant_horas > 40)
        {
            extra = (cant_horas - 40) * (pago * 1.5);
            salario = salario + extra;
        }
        printf("el salario es de $ %.2f \n\n", salario);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

agradezco la ayuda ! saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa se está completando de esa manera debido a que salario siempre es

```
 salario = pago * cantidad_horas;
```

Y si se superan las 40, se le suma el extra que se está calculando bien

```
 salario = salario + extra;
```

Bien, el problema reside que la primera línea que mencioné se ejecuta siempre. Si tú reemplazas verás el error:

```
 salario =  pago * cant_horas;  // salario = 10 * 41;
 ...
 salario = salario + extra; // salario = 410 + 15
```

Lo que debes hacer es ubicar esa primera línea dentro del if, ya que no puedes hacer la misma operación siempre o recibirás el error una y otra vez. Te quedará algo así:

```
...
if (cant_horas > 40){
     ...
     salario = 40 * pago + extra;
}
else {
     salario = cant_horas * pago;
}
...
```

Consejo, otra forma de sumar o realizar operaciones del formato  `a = a + b` pueden realizarse como `a += b`. Otras operaciones también cuentan con este "atajo". [Más información](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)